plt.colorbar() isn't working as I expected

I'm sure that the issue is caused by the fact that my x linspace doesn't start from 0, since changing it to 0 fixes the problem (but breaks the plot). How can I fix this?
I changed the linspace to 0 and the colorbar worked fine but the plot is wrong
x = np.linspace(0.95 * min_area, 1.05 * self.max_area,resolution) #area
y = np.linspace(0,1.05 * self.max_score,resolution) #log rank
    Z = [[None for _ in range(resolution)] for _ in range(resolution)]
    for i in range(len(x)):
        for j in range(len(y)):
            Z[j][i] = self.get_pareto_fitness(y[j], x[i], True)

im = plt.imshow(Z, extent=[0.95 * min_area, 1.05*self.max_area, 0, 1.05*self.max_score], interpolation='nearest', origin='lower', cmap='magma', aspect='auto') #cmap='viridis' 'magma', alpha=0.6

cbar = plt.colorbar(im)


On my side I am not able to reproduce the error, can you provide more context (such as the rest of the code or dummy data to test on)

Could you add the code that manipulated the colorbar after its creation? Did you relimit it?  What did you want to achieve? By default, the dark color will be mapped to the lowest value in Z (in the image it's about 0.9), and the light color the highest (here about 1.0).

You have three options, leave the colorbar "as is", specify vmin=0 so that the colorbar starts from zero, or the same with a custom colorbar.

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def from_zero_cmap(vmin, vmax, cmap='viridis', name='darkbottom'):
    from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
 
    v = plt.get_cmap(cmap)
    j = int(round(256*vmin/vmax))
    bottom = [v(0) for _ in range(j)]
    top = v(np.linspace(0, 1, 256-j))
    colors = np.vstack((bottom, top))
    return ListedColormap(colors, name=name)

N = 36
x = np.linspace(-0.5, 0.5, N)
y = x[:,None]
z = np.abs(np.sin(np.pi*(x+y)))/5+0.8 # 0.8 < z < 1.0
fig, (ax0, ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(9.0, 2.5), layout='constrained')

im0 = ax0.imshow(z, vmax=1)
cb0 = plt.colorbar(im0, ax=ax0)

im1 = ax1.imshow(z, vmin=0, vmax=1)
cb1 = plt.colorbar(im1, ax=ax1)

im2 = ax2.imshow(z, cmap=from_zero_cmap(0.8, 1.0), vmin=0, vmax=1)
cb2 = plt.colorbar(im2, ax=ax2)

plt.show()

